# Adding labels to GCP VPC and Subnetwork

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is there a way to add metadata(labels) on VPC networks and subnetworks similar to what is possible on projects and other compute engine resources?

I do not see an option in the console or in the REST API documentation.

My use case: After listing available subnets filter a few based on some metadata.

Answer (score 4):

You're only allowed to label the resources as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources):

> - Virtual machine instances
> - Forwarding rules (Alpha)
> - Images
> - Persistent disks
> - Persistent disk snapshots
> - Static external IP addresses (Alpha)
> - VPN tunnels (Alpha)

Therefore, I'm afraid there's no such functionality at the moment.

You can open a Feature Request on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559786) for this functionality, but you will most likely need a more detailed use case, - justifying as in why is it useful to have Cloud VPC network and subnetwork tags, and how it would help you.

If you wish, I can open the FR on your behalf once provided the information above.

Otherwise, if you don't want to disclose the use case, you can open [Support Case](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) and we will handle the process.